Why does curr1?.val ?? 0 + curr2?.val ?? 0 return 2 instead of 7?
I try to add two values of nullable items. I noticed that expression returns 2 instead of expected 7, but I would like to understand why.
Code:
public class ListNode
{
    public int val;
    public ListNode next;
    public ListNode(int val = 0, ListNode next = null)
    {
        this.val = val;
        this.next = next;
    }
}

ListNode curr1 = new ListNode(2);
ListNode curr2 = new ListNode(5);

int result = curr1?.val ?? 0 + curr2?.val ?? 0; // Expected result: 7, but getting 2

Console.WriteLine(result);

I know i could just use: (curr1?.val ?? 0)  + (curr2?.val ?? 0) but I'm just curious why the result is 2.

Please check out the Operator precedence + Operator associativity docs.

Because it is evaluated as (int?)2 ?? 5 ?? 0. Since the first term (int?)2 is not null, all the rest after the ?? is skipped.
